# remove white space before after of data in text area

Tags: php

I input string to textarea such as below:

```
         email1@gmail.com   
   email@gmail.com
 email3@gmail.com
      email4@gmail.com
```

How to format they to:

```
email1@gmail.com
email@gmail.com
email3@gmail.com
email4@gmail.com
```

One email in one line in textarea. I want use PHP to make it.
Please help me about solution, thanks you.

Comment: Please post what you have already tried.

Comment: Why you tagged JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work in php
`str_replace(' ','',$yourText)`

Comment: This solution is good, cover my problem.Thanks you!

Comment: Glad to hear that! you can accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all whitespace:

```html
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $yourstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the trim function to do this.

```
return(trim($str));
```

Comment: This is the most elegant *looking*, but wouldn't you have to break it up by newline characters first, if it's all in one variable?